# Call function from another python file in AWS Lambda

Tags: python, python-3.x, aws-lambda

I have a lambda deployment package containing two python files, file1.py and file2.py.
I need file1.py to call a function from file2.py and here's how I did it.

```
from file2 import function1

variable1 = function1()
print(variable1)
```

The above method works when I am in my virtual environment, but when I upload the deployment package to Lambda, I am getting a `None` result from function1.

PS: file2.py works perfectly and function1 can return the desired output when I run it individually.

Answer (score 0):

The solution is to ensure that the "Handler" value that you configure in AWS Lambda contain at least 2 `.` periods. To achieve this you need to put your code within a directory in your AWS Lambda code zip file and make that directory a module by adding an empty `__init__.py` file. The resulting structure looks like this

```sh
.
├── app
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── file1.py
│   └── file2.py
```

And you now change the "Handler" value from `file1.lambda_handler` to `app.file1.lambda_handler` (Handler in the 1st file). More explanation from this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14132789/relative-imports-for-the-billionth-time/14132912#14132912).